# Ansible playbook when usage

Tags: ansible

```
- name: restart dcache if mem low
  hosts: test
  tasks:
  - name: getMem
    shell: /bin/bash /etc/zabbix/shell/MonitorMem.sh
    register: memNum
  - name: restart dcache if mem low
    shell: killall -9 dcache
    when: memNum < 3
```

MonitorMem.sh returns a num(an integer) that represents free memory,I want to use when to decide whether execute restart action. but every time I run the playbook.it will skip restart action. please give me a hand, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [shell module's](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) documentation provides the structure of the return values and the key point is that it returns a data structure (dict) that contains, amongst other things, the "standard out" (output) of the shell command. The stdout is found in the `stdout` attribute of the returned dictionary. The `stdout_lines` attribute contains the same, but with each line as a separate array entry.

I added also a `int` jinja filter to convert the string value to an integer.

```
- name: restart dcache if mem low
  hosts: test

  tasks:
  - name: getMem
    shell: /bin/bash /etc/zabbix/shell/MonitorMem.sh
    register: memNum

  - name: restart dcache if mem low
    shell: killall -9 dcache
    when: memNum.stdout|int < 3
```